# Ajax Server Side Call 200 Response but not sending to $_POST

Tags: javascript, ajax, dynamic, get, server-side

Changing the question because the context changed.

I want to post the value of a Javascript variable to another page in the server using Ajax to POST and PHP to receive.

My Javascript code on page1.js:

```
var data = "test data";
var url = "page2.php";
var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
http.open("POST", url, true);
http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
http.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
        console.log(data);//this prints "test data" on my page1.js successfully
    }else{
    console.log(http.readyState); //this always shows different ready states
}
}
```

This is my "receiving" php code on page2.php:

```
if (isset($_POST)) {
  if (isset($_POST["data"])){
    echo "SUCCESS"; // I am only testing whether "data" was captured in the POST, for now.
  }
}
```

But it is not printing anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that with following code;

```
$.get("page1.php", function(data) {
  var html = $('<div>',{html:data});
  var my_content = html.find("#div1").text();
  $("#div2").html(my_content);
});
```

Here is a working fiddle: **http://jsfiddle.net/uKBL3/1/**

**Note:** I have used jsfiddle [json service](http://doc.jsfiddle.net/use/echo.html) for ajax simulation.

**Second way:** You can load page1.php in to a hidden div and read content from hidden div. By loading in to hiddendiv, your js codes will be triggered and dynamic content will be fetched. After that, you can read your data. Example:

```
$("#hidden_div").load("page2.php", function() {
    var html = $(this);
    var my_content = html.find("#div1").text();
    $("#div2").html(my_content);
})
```

Comment: 1: div#div1
accessKey: ""
align: ""
attributes: NamedNodeMap
baseURI: ""
childElementCount: 0
childNodes: NodeList[0]
children: HTMLCollection[0]
classList: DOMTokenList
className: ""
clientHeight: 0
clientLeft: 0
clientTop: 0
clientWidth: 0
contentEditable: "inherit"
dataset: DOMStringMap
dir: ""
draggable: false
firstChild: null
firstElementChild: null
hidden: false
id: "div1"
innerHTML: ""
innerText: ""
isContentEditable: false
lang: ""
lastChild: null
lastElementChild: null
localName: "div"
namespaceURI: "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
nextElementSibling: null

Comment: I didn't understand, what is that text

Comment: OK, your code did print in page2.php (this is the output from console.log) the div1. However, the textNode is dynamically generated through Javascript and it appears empty. See:  innerHTML: "" innerText: "" - so, how do I capture this content that prints in page1 after Javascript populates div1? Let me clarify, I ran the script only after page1 was populated, and still got the text nodes empty.

Comment: So, are there any other ways to get this content on the fly? Maybe "post" to page?

Comment: You can try second way on my anwser

Comment: That was really a great idea but still sending empty nodes. If I type hard html it will pass it. However the stuff that I am able to load with the dev tools does not. It does not load the whole thing from the local cache. That was a nice trick had it worked...

Comment: What kind of dynamic js content generation do you use? Maybe it is not triggered when loaded with js

Comment: I am trying to post the results of this tool to my server. http://hacks.bluesmoon.info/boomerang/doc/howtos/howto-1a-page%231.html - So this tool looks for a div called "results" and it writes the conclusions of the testing there.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47220/discussion-between-huseyin-babal-and-rebhelium)

Comment: Alright, this was not exactly what I needed but it worked and it helped solve the issue. The original issue is now resolved. I switched to Ajax submit and I am only calling the variables on submit with PHP.